# ng2-ckeditor set value by typescript

Tags: html, typescript, ckeditor, angular2-forms

I have created two ckeditor with `*ngfor`:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let lang of languages">
  <span>Texto legal en {{lang.translate}} {{lang.abbr}}</span>
  <ckeditor id="{{lang.abbr}}" formControlName="{{lang.abbr}}" [config]="config" (change)="onChange($event, lang.abbr)" (ready)="onReady($event)" (focus)="onFocus($event)" (blur)="onBlur($event)" debounce="500">
  </ckeditor>
</div>
```

Languages is an array with object like:

```
{abbr: "es", translation: "IDIOMA.es"}
```

If I compile this, it gets the following error:

```
There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name: 'en'
```

If I try to remove `formControlName="{{lang.abbr}}"`, it works but doesn't appear to save any data.

In component, I have the following:

```
let group = {
  'porcentaje': [setup.porcentaje || '', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)])]
}
for (let lang of this.languages) {
  group[lang.abbr] = [setup[lang.abbr] || '']
}

this.formRegister = this.fb.group(group);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the package correctly?

> https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor

According to the documentation, it is not possible to assign id and formControl. Try to replace the id with ngModel.

```
    <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let lang of languages">
        <span>Texto legal en {{lang.translate}} {{lang.abbr}}</span>
        <ckeditor [config]="config" (change)="onChange($event, lang.abbr)" (ready)="onReady($event)" (focus)="onFocus($event)" (blur)="onBlur($event)" debounce="500">
           <p id="{{lang.abbr}}">Try to use your Validators here!</p>
        </ckeditor>
      </div>
```